# Laravel form nullable user_id

Tags: php, laravel

How can I get `user_id` = null?

Logic:

I have testimonial where I can fill user info manually or just select one of my existing users, the problem is when I try to save testimonial with manual user i get `The user id must be a number.` error.

here is my store method:

```
$this->validate($request, array(
  // rest of code
  'user_id' => 'nullable|numeric',
));

$testimonial = new Testimonial;

  // rest of code
  $testimonial->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
  // rest of code
```

This is my form:

```
{{ Form::label('user_id', 'User') }}
<select class="form-control" name="user_id">
  <option>Select User</option>
  @foreach($users as $user)
    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->username }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Here is my schema:

```
Schema::create('testimonials', function (Blueprint $table) {
  // rest of code
  $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
});
Schema::table('testimonials', function (Blueprint $table) {
  // rest of code
  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

How can I pass to accept null on this field?

Comment: make sure your `select ` is same part of the form you submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates a validation failure and not a database problem. Your database will accept null values since testimonials.user_id is nullable.

The next step in debugging would be to check what `$request->input('user_id')` really is. You would need to temporarily disable the validation rules to accomplish this.

```
dd($request->input('user_id'));
```

You'll find that an option without value will use it's text as value. You're not sending an empty string, you're sending the string "Select User" which of course isn't numeric. Instead, change your html code to let that option have an empty value.

```
<option value="">Select User</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

`$testimonial->user_id = $request->input('user_id');`

to

```
 $testimonial->user_id = (int) $request->input('user_id');
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your user_id is acting as a `foreign key` in testimonials table, it should be present in `users` table also. 
When you manually try to enter the record, probably you are assigning it the id that is not present in users table.
You can't have a `foreign key` and a `NULL` at the same time. Just remove the constraint and it will work fine for both scenarios

Comment: When I'm not selecting any existing user i just leave that column empty and not assign anything `<option>Select User</option>`

Comment: Then you should remove the `foreign key` constraint

Comment: and if for next entry i want use existence user instead manual one? :)

Comment: You can, just remove the constraint, you will still be able to add the existing user record. Trick is, you need to keep in you mind that this column is acting as a foreign key, just don't tell `Mysql` to do that :)

Comment: It is present in the users table, it's the primary key there. All major databases support nullable foreign keys. The error isn't even coming from the database...

Comment: @mafortis, change `<option value='0'>Select User</option>` may be the error is because there is no value coming